# How do I create a file upload progress bar in PHP?

Tags: php

In my PHP web site, i want to create a file uploading progress bar. I have used many code, but it's not working. My PHP version is 5.2.8 and sever is in Linux. Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS from APC.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.apc.php

The tutorial Kalium posted shows how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here, have a [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-v525/index.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: learn how HTML, Internet communication, and server-side processing work. Understand that your problem is not related to PHP. HAND.